Buffer I/O error on unexistent device
I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 via the live disk. I have two internal disks one /dev/nvme0n1p1 which is data, and the other one /dev/nvme1n1p2 containing my system.
Now, time by time when I put my laptop in sleep mode, at wakeup I obtain a black screen, no action is possible not even trying to exit from X11 and try to get a terminal. My laptop does have a secure boot which I disabled thinking it was because of something related to it and once I did that rather than a blank screen I got the following message

Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 33, lost async page write

The thing is, I don't have that nvme0n1p2 under my /dev directory, and looking into the fstab file I can read this message

/ was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation

I tried to look into grub and gdm configuration but found nothing. I tried to search for a possible root cause or solution online but the majority of posts I read were about existing disk issues.
It can be somewhere in my system there's still stored this disk?
Did I do something wrong during the installation?
